# Listener en JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Buenas noches, me he topado con un pequeño problema al escribir el código de una interfaz. La parte del código que falla es:

```
final BooleanBinding activarComprobacion = campo1.textProperty().isEqualsTo("");
activarComprobacion.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Bolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
    System.out.println("Tendria que salir esto al seleccionar alguna opcion de campo1");
}
```

No da error de compilación ni nada por el estilo, de hecho, antes utilizaba un botón para la comprobación y todo iba bien. Dentro de la función lambda hacía varias cosas, pero lo he quitado porque era irrelevante.

Comment: Editado. Para bloques de código, se pueden poner si pones 4 espacios delante de cada línea (más luego los necesarios para indentar el código).

Answer (score 1):

he probado esta solución con un TextField y funciona haciendo uso de un ChangeListener. Hazme saber si resuelve tu problema, Saludos.

```
campo1.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(newValue.equals("")){
            System.out.println("Tendria que salir esto al seleccionar alguna opcion de campo1");
        }
    });
```